# critique on Kafka by Howard Fast

Tags: meaning

> *Very near the top of what I have in the past rather indelicately called the “cultural dung heap of reaction” sits Franz Kafka, **one of the major Olympians in that curious shrine the so-called “new critics” and their Trotskyite colleagues have erected**.*

I am not sure whether I fully understand the emphasized part of the above sentence. Is it so that the curious shrine where should be Kafka was erected by new critics and their Trotskyite collegues. Does the word Olympians have the same or similar meaning as idols or icons in that sentence?

Comment: I don't get the "Trotskyite" reference if the author is referring the New Criticism. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Criticism

Comment: @TRomano Trotsky was expelled from the Party in 1927 and regarded thereafter as a counter-revolutionary. Fast, writing as a hard-line Communist in 1950, aligns him with the socially very conservative New Critics - even though  Trotsky had in 1924 written a highly influential critique of the Formalists, the Russian counterparts of the New Critics.

Comment: He wasn't writing for history, then - he was assuming that knowledge would continue to be right at the forefront of everyone's thoughts, forever... Nowadays, it functions as a rant, but that subtlety is lost to this generation.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't think I would characterize Fast's posture as 'subtle' in any sense - it's just following the party line.

Answer (score 2):

The author is in no doubt over his dislike of the adoration of Kafka, I'd say...

Break it down...

One of the major Olympians = one of the main people (joke to follow, whether it's funny or not)...

of the curious shrine... ah, now we see the joke (& no, it wasn't funny), a back-reference to a place of worship of the ancient Greek gods, who lived on Mount Olympus. Curious is spurious (couldn't resist that one;-) just heightening the level of disagreement of the author with his subject.

this 'virtual shrine' was created by so-called new critics - that is, people who have been named as new rather than old critics; implying young thinkers, with ideas that the 'old school' of established critics find strange or opposing to their own ideas. Just like your grandfather hated your father's love of rock & roll... which these days we find rather tame. History can be cyclic like that...

& their Trotskyite colleagues - which is just a rant about someone you don't agree with, by comparing them to a specific historical political movement, unpopular in modern culture.

..have erected - these people we dislike built the shrine. We can now recreate the entire sentence backwards to actually understand what the author was ranting about...

"People I disagree with have made it clear that in their thinking they support the idea that Kafka was a 'god' in his field; one of the most important ones."

*Edit:* btw, I do think it's a fabulous sentence. It spits venom & bile in exactly the manner I presume the author intended. I just chose to make light of the process of dissecting it.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis. Yes, Fast's stalinst-like rhetoric is ridiculous.

Comment: I did find it quite amusing; though it is well constructed.

Comment: Absolutely. I agree it's quite a neat/articulate piece of invective. But unless I had other good reasons to respect the author's "critical credentials", my default assumption would be that I'm not dealing with an objective critic about to make some cogently-argued or subtle point.